# Javascript search for all occurences of a character in the dom?

Tags: javascript

I would like to find all occurrence of the $ character in the dom, how is this done?

Comment: Once you've found them what do you want to do? Add elements around them and highlight them?

Comment: Need to get a reference point, so I can get the numeric value next to the sign for example documents containing $4.00, I need to pick up the 4.00 string part.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do something semantic like wrap $4.00 in a span element?

```
<span class="money">$4.00</span>
```

Then you would find elements belonging to class 'money' and manipulate them very easily. You could take it a step further...

```
<span class="money">$<span class="number">4.00</span></span>
```

I don't like being a jQuery plugger... but if you did that, jQuery would probably be the way to go.

Comment: Easily done in JS even without JQuery: `var prices = getElementsByClassName("number");` is really all you need.

Comment: @nico - `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in IE though... and personally I think it would be best to get the elements of class `money` and then get the elements of class `number` within them. A valid point nonetheless.

Comment: Damn IE... I thought they put it at least in IE8 but no, you're right

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, though probably not the best, is to walk the DOM to find all the text nodes. Something like this might suffice:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var i, j, nodes;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    nodes = elements[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        if (nodes[j].nodeType !== 3) { // Node.TEXT_NODE
            continue;
        }
        // regexp search or similar here
    }
}
```

although, this would only work if the `$` character was always in the same text node as the amount following it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a Regular Expression search on the innerHTML of the body tag:

For instance - on this page:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var dollars = body.innerHTML.match(/\$[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*/g)
```

Results (at the time of my posting):

```
["$4.00", "$4.00", "$4.00"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this if you just need a bunch of strings and don't need a reference to the nodes containing `$` would be to use a regular expression on the body's text content. Be aware that `innerText` and `textContent` aren't exactly the same. The main difference that could affect things here is that `textContent` contains the contents of `<script>` elements whereas `innerText` does not. If this matters, I'd suggest traversing the DOM instead.

```
var b = document.body, bodyText = b.textContent || b.innerText || "";
var matches = bodyText.match(/\$[\d.]*/g);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to add my 2 cents for prototype. Prototype has some very simple DOM traversal functions that might get exactly what you are looking for.

*edit* so here's a better answer

the `decendants()` function collects all of the children, and their children and allows them to be enumerated upon using the `each()` function

```
$('body').descendants().each(function(item){
   if(item.innerHTML.match(/\$/))
   {
      // Do Fun scripts
   }
});
```

or if you want to start from `document`

```
 Element.descendants(document).each(function(item){
   if(item.innerHTML.match(/\$/))
   {
      // Do Fun scripts
   }
});
```

Comment: There isn't a solution to JL's problem here... just a plug for prototype. Explain more concretely how prototype could be used to solve specifically this problem! I, for one, haven't used it, and would appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain what I was vaguely referring to - thanks for poking me in the eye :-)